# Why does this tiny script not work in 4.0?

Tags: python

This script works till 3.6, but not 4.0.

```
import bpy

for a in bpy.context.screen.areas:
    if a.type == 'DOPESHEET_EDITOR':

        #deselect the keyframes
        bpy.ops.action.select_all({"area" : a}, action="DESELECT")
        break
```

4.0 says "ValueError: 1-2 args execution context is supported" in `bpy.ops.action.select_all`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From version 3.2, context overriding this way is deprecated and is no more available in 4.0. Have a look for instance [here](https://devtalk.blender.org/t/deprecationwarning-passing-in-context-overrides-is-deprecated-in-favor-of-context-temp-override/27870) and this is also documented in Blender wiki [here](https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Reference/Release_Notes/4.0/Python_API).

What you can do instead is the following:

```
import bpy

for a in bpy.context.screen.areas:
    if a.type == 'DOPESHEET_EDITOR':

        with bpy.context.temp_override(area=a):
            bpy.ops.action.select_all(action="DESELECT")
        
        break
```

The Python `with` block allows to define the life time of this temporary override (the override is finished after this block).

If you need something that is compatible with version older than 3.2, you can test Blender version using `bpy.app.version`.